# PostgreSQL Database Queries Dropping in JSP Queries

Tags: jsp, postgresql-9.1

So I am working on a postgres database.  I am using JSP to connect the database to my html page.  I send my queries from a select tag and once I get the response back I append the geojson to a leaflet map.  Where it gets odd is the fact the queries work half the time but then fail other times.  I am using Mars Eclipse to test the program.  I have also viewed the output on a number of browsers.  I am running on localhost.  Does anybody know why the queries would work sometimes and not others?  I have never seen anything like this with programming.  It has always worked or not worked.  It seems very odd indeed.  Also, I am getting the responses back as innerHTML and then doing some scripting to format the data as needed in arrays.  I know there must be a better way to get the responses back but this is one of my first database applications and I am happy just to see the points on the map.  If anybody has any better ideas as to how I should be putting my points on the map, please feel free to share.  However, my only real concern is the fact the queries drop from time to time.  Maybe it has something to do with the fact it is running on local machine rather than an actual server - I don't know.  Here is the code and thanks to any helpful responses.

HTML

```
<html><head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="myCSS.css"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script>
myGlobalArray = [];
myArrayResponse = [];
j=0;
function myFun(){
    var map = L.map('map',{ center: [41.77, -87.5333], zoom: 9});
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>' }).addTo(map);
    myGlobalArray.push(map);
 }




function showUser(str, myInt) {

if (str == "categories") {return;} 

else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();} 
    else {xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           var theDiv = document.getElementById("map");

           myArrayResponse = this.responseText.split(";");


myArrayResponse.splice(0,1);myArrayResponse.splice(myArrayResponse.length-1,1);
        myArrayFun(str);    
      }
    };
if(myInt == 1){xmlhttp.open("GET","callQuery.jsp?q="+str,true);}



    xmlhttp.send();

 }
}


function myArrayFun(theStr){
    alert(myArrayResponse[1]);
    if(typeof(myArrayResponse[1])== "undefined"){alert(theStr);
     //showUser(theStr,1);
     //function call above become infinite loop if input fails
     }





  var geoF = [JSON.parse(myArrayResponse[1]),{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-87.723, 41.5]}];

  var geojsonMarkerOptions = {radius: 3,fillColor: "#ff7800",color: "#000",weight: 1,opacity: 1,fillOpacity: 0.8};
  var thegeoj;
  for(r=0;r<myArrayResponse.length;r++){
   i = r;
   try {

    var theP = JSON.parse(myArrayResponse[r]);
    var thegeoj=    L.geoJSON(theP, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
        }
    }).addTo(myGlobalArray[0]);
    } catch(err) {

    }

 }
 alert(i);

 }


 </script>

 </head>






 <body onload="myFun()">
 <div id="header" onclick="myArrayFun()"><strong><font color="black">  

 <h1> <center>WEATHER APPLICATION</center></h1> </font></strong>
 </div>


 <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>

 <div id="leftContainer" >
<select id="myCat" onchange="showUser(this.value, 1)">
    <option value="categories">Categories</option>
    <option value="HOMICIDE">Homicide</option>
    <option value="PROSTITUTION">Prostitution</option>
    <option value="ARSON">Arson</option>
</select>     



</div>



<div id="footer"><center>Last Updated January 28, 2017!</center></div> 


</body>
</html>
```

JSP

```
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@page import="javax.servlet.*" %>

<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>

<%@page import="java.util.*,java.sql.*,java.io.*" %>



<html>

<%!Connection con1; %>

<%!Statement s1; %>

<%!ResultSet rs1; %>

<% String name=request.getParameter("q");

try{

Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

con1=DriverManager.getConnection

("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/chicagoTest","postgres","pass123");

s1=con1.createStatement();

rs1=s1.executeQuery("select ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) from myschema.spatialdata2 where ptype='"+name+"'");

}catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

%>;

<% while(rs1.next())

{ %>
<%=rs1.getString(1)%>;



<% } %>

</html>
```

Comment: So I got rid of a few things to try and make the example a little easier to understand.  I got rid of a few of the leaflet markers as they are irrelevant to the question.  If you look at the HTML section you will see a commented out call back to the AJAX function showUser.  This call becomes an infinite loop when the input fails.  However, it can fail on one try and work on the next if the calls are simply made in the select options.  Any ideas?

Comment: So I actually tested the call back to the AJAX function "showUser" and it worked after a few iterations but when I first tested it the query came back as undefined about 20 times.  I guess it is a solution but it seems like risky business using such an algorithm.  Probably a good idea to put some limit on the number of times the function will get called.  That way you avoid the program entering an infinite loop.